# Python logging port 514 folder/yyyy/mm/dd

Tags: python, logging, python-2.x, socketserver

Hi i want to log 514 udp port with python script. Log address does not change when date changes.I want to save all log diary. I want to record the log with the same name in different folder every day.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, stat
import datetime
import logging
import SocketServer

HOST, PORT = "0.0.0.0", 514
class SyslogUDPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        data = bytes.decode(self.request[0].strip())
        socket = self.request[1]
        today = datetime.datetime.now()
        year = today.strftime("%Y")
        month=today.strftime("%m")
        day=today.strftime("%d")
        file_path = "/listen/"  + year +"/" + month + "/" + day 
        file= file_path + "/test.log"       
        if(not os.path.exists(file_path)):
            os.makedirs(file_path)
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(message)s', datefmt='', filename=file, filemode='a')
        logging.info(str(data))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        server = SocketServer.UDPServer((HOST,PORT), SyslogUDPHandler)
        server.serve_forever(poll_interval=0.5)
    except (IOError, SystemExit):
        raise
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ("Crtl+C Pressed. Shutting down.")
```

Comment: What is your question or what's wrong with your script?

Comment: script create only start date . Not changing when date changes

Answer (score 0):

I can't really test this, but I think the problem may be because your code always *appends* data to the logging file. So try doing this instead:

```
class SyslogUDPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        data = bytes.decode(self.request[0].strip())
        socket = self.request[1]

        today = datetime.datetime.now()
        year = today.strftime("%Y")
        month = today.strftime("%m")
        day = today.strftime("%d")
        file_path = "/listen/" + year + "/" + month + "/" + day
        file = file_path + "/test.log"
        if os.path.exists(file_path):
            filemode = 'a'  # Append to existing file.
        else:
            os.makedirs(file_path)
            filemode = 'w'  # Write to new file.

        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(message)s',
                            datefmt='', filename=file, filemode=filemode)
        logging.info(str(data))
```

Comment: This code logging like our script. When start logging , file created every date but logging only first date .

Answer (score 0):

change line

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(message)s', datefmt='', filename=file, filemode=('a' if os.path.exists(file_path) else 'w'))
```

to

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(message)s', datefmt='', filename=file, filemode=('a' if os.path.exists(file_path) else 'w'))
```

Final code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, stat
import datetime
import logging
import SocketServer

HOST, PORT = "0.0.0.0", 514
class SyslogUDPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        data = bytes.decode(self.request[0].strip())
        socket = self.request[1]
        today = datetime.datetime.now()
        year = today.strftime("%Y")
        month=today.strftime("%m")
        day=today.strftime("%d")
        file_path = "/listen/"  + year +"/" + month + "/" + day 
        file= file_path + "/test.log"       
        if(not os.path.exists(file_path)):
            os.makedirs(file_path)
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(message)s', datefmt='', filename=file, filemode=('a' if os.path.exists(file_path) else 'w'))
        logging.info(str(data))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        server = SocketServer.UDPServer((HOST,PORT), SyslogUDPHandler)
        server.serve_forever(poll_interval=0.5)
    except (IOError, SystemExit):
        raise
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ("Crtl+C Pressed. Shutting down.")
```

Comment: This code logging like our script. When start logging , file created every date but logging only first date